# How do you disable the Forum in DNN 4?

Tags: windows, forum, dotnetnuke

I have a dot net nuke 4 site with that has a forum.  It is getting a lot spam and I wanted to know how I could disable the forum.  Screenshots of the solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stop anyone from using the forum, simply delete it from the page.

If you want to secure the forum to a smaller group of users.  Modify the "Settings" for the module and change the roles that can view the module.

Answer (score 0):

First at all you have to log in with an Admin account or a SuperUser one, 
Then navigate to the default forum page
After that in Page Functions, you have the options for delete

[alt text http://web9.twitpic.com/img/30317764-7ad729c043eb36ce9cd6285d2a81931e.4ab24c13-scaled.jpg](http://web9.twitpic.com/img/30317764-7ad729c043eb36ce9cd6285d2a81931e.4ab24c13-scaled.jpg)